# Python POST request with XPATH

Tags: python, xml, post, python-requests

Please help me convert a working URL request in the web browser to a python request module executable request.

My working browser request URL:

https://192.168.100.25/api?type=config&action=set&xpath=/config/devices/entry[@name=%27localhost.localdomain%27]/network/interface/ethernet/entry[@name=%27ethernet1/1%27]/layer3/ip&element=%3Centry%20name=%279.6.6.6/24%27/%3E

This device basically accepts Rest API calls in XML format. Please help me, convert this to a python requests POST request.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do this with Python Requests:

> url = '''https://192.168.100.25/api?
>   type=config&action=set&xpath=/config/devices&element='''
>
> out = requests.post(url, verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))

This is working.

Please let me know if there is an easier and proper way to do this.